# AspMvcAction annotation with default controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I am using jquery autocomplete, the source is provided with jquery ajax, calling my `AutocompleteController`. The `AutocompleteController` has different Actions, like `GetCustomers`, `GetItems`, `GetCountries`, ...

This is my `UrlHelper` extension method:

```
public static string Autocomplete(this UrlHelper url, [AspMvcAction] string actionName, [AspMvcController] string controller = "Autocomplete")
{
  return url.Action(actionName, controller, new { area = "" });
}
```

And in Razor:

```
@Url.Autocomplete("GetCountries", "Autocomplete")
```

[image: working]

Because of the `[AspMvcAction]` and `[AspMvcController]` the intellisense is working without problems. But the `controller` parameter in the `@Url.Autocomplete` is redundant, so I would rather have:

```
@Url.Autocomplete("GetCountries")
```

[image: error]

But in this case ReSharper searches the action (`GetCountries` in this case) in the controller of the current view, that's why it cannot find it (Cannot resolve action 'GetCountries').

Any ideas how to convince ReSharper to look in the `Autocomplete` controller?

PS - the problem is only with intellisense, the code works in both cases.

Comment: I really need this feature. Did you find another solution or did you file a ticket on the JetBrains issue tracker site? I couldn't find an open ticket but maybe I'll create one too.

Comment: I found an existing question asking for something similar (albeit slightly different as the feature request wants a fixed controller name instead of a default name that can be overridden). I added a comment to it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-406269

Comment: Sadly, its an 8-year-old feature request so I doubt this will be added anytime soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported.

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008302300-AspMvcAction-annotation-with-default-controller